# web.config Authorization settings not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am attempting to add a group of authorized users to a web.config file

So I added in this

```
<authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrators" />
      <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

(based on what I read here [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

When I look at the Administrators group under local users and groups, I am in the list. I am not sure why this isn't working.

I continue to get prompted for credentials when I navigate to my site. After a couple failed logins I get 401.1 Unauthorized

(yes I have a role manger section also as outlined here [Roles authentication works using Authorization attribute but not via authorization in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479983/roles-authentication-works-using-authorization-attribute-but-not-via-authorizati))

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyAspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="SqlServer" applicationName="/" name="MyAspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Removed" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="MyAspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Removed" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I have also tried it with other groups and users as well.

It even fails when ONLY I do

```
<allow users="*"/>
```

Comment: Am I reading that right? You're using a Sql Server for the role provider? If that's the case, then the roles will be in the sql server not in the local users and groups on your machine.

Comment: derp.... thank you let me go check that

Comment: @JoelEtherton so I understand what you're pointing at and I agree this is a indication why the normal windows users and groups isn't working. However, shouldn't user="*" work?

Comment: I would think, but it's also possible that there is a configuration problem with your provider. If I recall correctly (and don't quote me on this) the authorization will fail if the provider fails for any reason.